# Background-color top and right

Tags: html

I tried to set the background-color to a div, but the top of the div remain uncolored.
I tried padding-top and padding-right, but it is not working.

I need some help,please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*{
padding:0 ;margin:0;
}
```

Every browser has its own user agent style sheet. So you have to overide it before starting HTML/CSS.

Use the above code.

for detailed explanation refer [here](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is in the body.
Add this to your css file

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```